# How can I solve a problem in the firts render?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a function that must be rerun every time the "refresh" parameter changes, so I write it into a useEffect. When the function runs, I set data in a table so I want that only table changes in my page.
I set the "refresh" parameter with values true or false in an other function that runs thanks to a Click.
The problem is that on the first render the table doesn't change. How can I solve?

```
const [info, setInfo] = useState([]);
const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(false);

const onSubmitChecked = (event) => {
    (...sending updated data to the server)

    setRefresh(prevRefresh => !prevRefresh);
    closeWindow();
    
  };


useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    getData()
      .then((response) => {
        if (response && response.data) {
          const { data } = response;
          setInfo(data);
          setTableData(info);
          setIsLoading(false);
        } else {
          setTableData([]);
          setIsLoading(false);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setTableData([]);
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  }, [refresh]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do seperate `useEffect`

#### Create common function

```
const getAndSetData = () => {
  setIsLoading(true)
  getData()
      .then((response) => {
        if (response && response.data) {
          const { data } = response;
          setInfo(data);
          setTableData(info);
          setIsLoading(false);
        } else {
          setTableData([]);
          setIsLoading(false);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setTableData([]);
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
}
```

#### Set useEffect for initial mount

```
useEffect(() => getAndSetData(), [])
```

#### Set useEffect for refresh changes

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if(refresh){
      getAndSetData()
    }
    //Potentially: setRefresh(false) here
  }, [refresh])
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I solved my issue adding:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(refresh){
      getAndSetData()
    }
    getAndSetData();
  }, [refresh])
```